# layout falls apart on ie8 on some machines

Tags: css, layout, iis-6, internet-explorer-8

I issued a strange behaviour from IE8. We uploaded asp.net application on iis6.
Everything works fine and layout is in place.
But on my colleague machine, with same browser(IE8), layout falls a part and on the some of the other machines too(!??)
It is strange because it is: the same server, same operating systems and the same browser

Anyone has ideas why this is the case?

Thanks

Comment: @Chacha102 - Thats about the long and short of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite piece of code for dealing with IE8 issues is as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Just pop that in the header of the document and ff the site works and behaves correctly in IE8 after that, then it's a problem with the browsers updated rendering engine and not your code.  Give it a whirl.

Comment: No problem. IE is the bane of most web developers. The more we share, the better the web will inevitably be.

Comment: @Andrew: Or if your site is standards compliant you can use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">` to ensure an IE8 visitor can't put the browser into compatibility mode. http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The IE7 Compatibility Mode is probably enabled on one of the browsers, which makes IE8 behave more IEish (Microsoft Standards Mode instead of W3C Standards). Check if the button that looks like a broken page (or if `Tools > Compatibility View`) is enabled.